# Issues with Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I tried to deploy Hyperledger Blockchain Explorer for Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 as per instructions available here: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

However, whenever I try to launch main.js I get the following error:

```
`[2017-11-17 20:57:53.785] [ERROR] Helper - Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: write EPROTO 140480353146688:error:1411713E:SSL routines:ssl_check_srvr_ecc_cert_and_alg:ecc cert not for signing:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c:2520:
140480353146688:error:14082130:SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:bad ecc cert:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:3550:
]
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClientImpl.js:711:12)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:408:12)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:430:5)
at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:39:7)
at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:561:3)
[2017-11-17 20:57:53.787] [ERROR] Helper - admin enrollment failed`
```

I made sure that config.json is configured correctly. I did not edit tls settings or paths. Certificates generated by first-network (./byfn.sh) are definitely correct because the byfn setup ends up with success.

I assume there is something wrong with the way certificates are handled by Explorer but I have no clue where to search for solution.

Any help with the above will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try running it with tls disabled?

Comment: Yes I did, without any positive outcome.

Comment: Can post network config files of both blockchain-explorer & fabric?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper credentials of CA(ca folder present inside msp folder of each organization in the network) in docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml.

For Eg.

- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
- FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f0a8e7e64651071b720e47eb4c71a3610cadb185a1ace6c029d8b41688fde6b2_sk

In volumes section give mappings in this way  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config

Instead of using localhost in the url, use the IP used by the Docker(Applicable only when you are using Docker QuickStart Terminal)(In my case, it was 192.168.99.100).

In enrollAdmin.js file,

var caRootsPath = "./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"
    let data = fs.readFileSync(caRootsPath);
    let caroots = Buffer.from(data).toString();

```
var tlsOptions = {
    trustedRoots: caroots,
    verify: true // Make it false if some error like Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP: 192.168.99.100 is not in the cert's list occurs. This error can also be removed if you have admin access to your computer. 
};
// be sure to change the http to https when the CA is running TLS enabled
fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('https://192.168.99.100:7054', tlsOptions , 'ca-org1', crypto_suite);
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case, you are using a test or local TLS Fabric peer you also have to do the following: https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

"If you are connecting to a non TLS fabric peer: please modify the protocol (grpcs->grpc) and port (9051-> 9050) in the peer url and remove the tls_cacerts"

I am able to see a blank page with a "cannot GET/" and swagger API link: http://localhost:9000/api-docs/#/ coming up fine now. I just have to figure out where the business network specific keys/certs are stored.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has threw out again when I am using Hyperledger Fabric 1.2 version to deploy the blockchain explorer, yet the solution above all cannot solve my that problem:

```
unknown protocol SSL routines:ssl3_check_cert_and_algorithm:bad ecc cert:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c:3550:
```

At first, I think it was caused by version incompatible since it seems works fine before I upgrade my network to the fabric 1.2 or 1.1. However, it is unnecessary to downgrade my fabric network to 1.0 for the sake of blockchain explorer. The other similar issues opened at [github](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/issues/167)/[composer](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3250) do gives me some hints about the problem but still cannot totally solve it.

Using synchronize debug tool like `node --inspect-brk:0.0.0.0:9229 server.js` do helps me solved this problem:

My error log is the same as the log printed above, happening at `FabricCAClientImpl.js:711:12`. To go to definition of the code, it throw an error on:

```
request.on('error', function (err) {
reject(new Error(util.format('Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [%s]', err)));
});
```

The function is called after using `self._httpClient.request` to send http request:

```
var request = self._httpClient.request(requestOptions, function (response)
```

Check out the definition of the `self._httpClient`, it shows that the module `https` is imported at the head of the code. That is why some solution recommend us to change the `TLS_ENABLE`D from `false` to `true`, and modify `grpcs` to `grpc` in the configuration file. But in latter version, fabric are using connection profile to help us to load the keycerts.

The official connection profile sample file use `https` as default, but we can change it to the `http` url and force the client to use the http policy, like:

```
ca:
  url: http://localhost:7054
  httpOptions:
     verify: true
```